# Check type without inferring checked type

Tags: typescript

Consider following type

```
interface ISmth<T> {
  id: number;
  data: T;
}
```

And now I want to declare an array containing such items

```
var a = [{
  id: 1,
  data: [],
}, {
  id: 2,
  data: 4,
}, {
  id: 3,
  data: "abc",
}] as const
```

I want to use `as const` as this array will never be changed and it contains different types of `data` property, which I want to distinguish.

But at the same time I want typescript to ensure, that every array element is presented by `ISmth<any>`. How can I express such validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to enforce type constraints on `a`:

**Compile time only type assertion**

This is the solution proposed by @Qwertiy, which uses an interface extending the `never` type in the failed type assertion case to enforce a compile error. In addition, a compile error can also be triggered with help of a [generic type constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). If we allow the assertion type to be generic and receive arbitrary multiple types, it could be written like this ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=12&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWAeAFQD5kBvAKGSuWABMAuZEAV0wCNoBuS62uMOIwLcAvuXIA3OFGRxkAXmQBtCtRoNkARgA0PKnwGMlAXV0jjsgM7IEAexCWw4qTLgBRKFFszFKvesYAIhhbW0DdNQNBZVNycysbe0dxMABPAAcUAEFLS2gwHMtgAHMQODYAGwhCbWQAVWQIAA9IEFprYgVkMChmCBSM7Nz8rsL8wpKyyuqoCDhaewrUtCxcPDgQVKITWrTM2xhZEnI9obyoMA8vH2Qxi4nS8qq8WfnF5YxsfA2tne7Bg6yK7eEhAA)):

```
type AssertAssignable<T, U extends T> = true

var a = [{
    id: 1,
    data: [],
}] as const

var aError = [{
    id: "foo",
    data: [],
}] as const

type Assert = AssertAssignable<readonly ISmth<any>[], typeof a> 
type AssertError = AssertAssignable<readonly ISmth<any>[], typeof aError> // error(OK!)
```

**Type assertion involving a helper function** (for sake of completeness moved from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58563435/how-to-use-unused-interface/58569735))

A helper function `createA` can be defined, whose sole purpose is to assert types on the created object literal for `a`, while still keeping the type narrowed via `as const` ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noUnusedLocals=true&ssl=34&ssc=13&pln=26&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWAeAFQD5kBvAWAChkblgATALmRAFdMAjaAbituXpwwcZgV6UAvlSoxWIBGGAB7EMgRQIQiAEE825BAAekEPQDOyAEqb6KgDYBPPBmz44IB0QDaAXSJEAChFkbQBKZn0KaloNMFYoVTgqKUoqADc4KGQ4ZABeNQ0tbQCvKP4GZgBGABo+WkFhZl9kn2yLBBUzMFDxdMzsgFEoKCUs-PVNSGLSupoK5AAiSoXq5AB6NYNh0eQAgHkAaQBCUNmBIWDmyVa4ds7u3soMrLhUEDtQFHyAvQNjCFMFmscFs7ycLlweHcnl8-iCEVCeRIcFCJTKtHmNTODUuPlq1zaanup1SpNk8kUKgMIBgoyQBAcAAcIPQADLASBQOB2QiBRHomixeKqX5GEzmZDEeEhRG5ZHJaSUAG0qD0pks9mc7l4QqgxxoLCQ6HeHxUPlos6Y-H8HFNU0E25EkBdElUIA)):

```
function createA<A extends Readonly<ISmth<any>[]>>(a: A): A {
    return a
}

var a = createA([{
    id: 1,
    data: []
}] as const);

var aError = createA([{
    id: "1", // error (OK!)
    data: []
}] as const);
```

You could even make the assertion inline using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), if `createA` is not reused:

```
var aInline = (<A extends Readonly<ISmth<any>[]>>(a: A) => a)([{
    id: 1,
    data: [],
}] as const)
```

... or define a generic exportable utility helper.

```
function enforceTypedLiteral<T>() {
    return <A extends T>(a: A) => a
}

enforceTypedLiteral<readonly ISmth<any>[]
>()([{
    id: 1,
    data: []
}] as const)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=26&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWAeAFQD5kBvAWAChllgATALmRAFdMAjaAbiprrjBwmBHpQC+VKgDc4UZHGQBeZAG0K1Wo2QBGADS9k-QUxUBdfeN1kD9JgCYLfAUOQAWC2Kvqat5AGZHQ2cmACI4dgQQj1N5AGdkBAB7EFiwSUowAE8ABxQCJWQACizcxJh5ZAgAD0gQOniAJQg4OmSAG0y8DGx8OBBMojMSAH5kAHl2ACsIBDBkJhAIKWgASlFQSFhEFAANSpqIOvj80mQxIA):

```
interface ISmth<T> {
  id: number;
  data: T;
}

var a = [{
  id: 1,
  data: [],
}, {
  id: 2,
  data: 4,
}, {
  id: 3,
  data: "abc",
}] as const

type T = (typeof a extends Readonly<ISmth<any>[]> ? Object : never);
interface X extends T { }
```

So if condition is met, `T` stands for `Object` and code compiles.
Otherwice `T` is `never`, interface can't extend `never` and produses an error.