# How to use unused interface

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript with `noUnusedLocals` turned on and don't want to turn it off.

But now I'm trying to apply some kind of additional assertion like [described here](/a/58437579/4928642):

```
interface ISmth<T> {
  id: number;
  data: T;
}

var a = [{
  id: 1,
  data: [],
}, {
  id: 2,
  data: 4,
}, {
  id: 3,
  data: "abc",
}] as const;

type ObjectIfImplemented = (typeof a extends Readonly<ISmth<any>[]> ? Object : never);
interface AssertThatReallyImplemented extends ObjectIfImplemented { }
```

So I need interface `AssertThatReallyImplemented` as a compilation assertion (if it compiles, everythimg is fine, if not - I have to fix something), but I'm not going to use it anywhere.

Is there a better way of disposing error

> 'AssertThatReallyImplemented' is declared but never used.

then exporting interface somehow like

```
export type _BypassNoUnusedLocalsLimitation = AssertThatReallyImplemented;
```

Comment: Suggest renaming the title to something like "Use a type assertion with object literal and as const". That title sounds a bit paradox ;)

Comment: @ford04, there is already [a question about that](/q/58437445/4928642). But currently I'm actually trying to use interface for [this check](//www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAzlAvFA2lgugGmwAYDjCTCsjzzSqaprG6nWGKzH32Xuv-WvAXzbNKoiSNq4A3AFgAUKEhQAggCcIAZQCGAWwgAeGIQCqhAEoA+DNhi4oEAB7AIAOwAmaLKYcB+bF9HF3cvO38oCygALig3CAA3CHUYuMTk+QUASzdXdQAzHQBjaABJN3gkVErkABl3AHNgAAsAUQBHOB1EFHKPZ2DXTzQNbX0jAG9sAGkIECgcqAAKGtRB0LQc-OTYKACprGmFtygAazmAe3zYXFij5yGw85Ar3YCj2PiklIBfVK-kgBKLBuOB6ABGyVwtygs3mP0IBzhx1gCGQKBBYMh6lwWAARMg3E1mnjobEkSjnq9VigYUcfoc5g4EVAAPLggBWECKwBsUx+iiAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `noUnusedLocals` compiler option and a non-exported type assertion interface, you could use a [@ts-ignore](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) comment to suppress the `'AssertThatReallyImplemented ' is declared but its value is never read` error.

To do so, we separate above "undeclared" error from the actual type assertion error by using a placeholder type `_`, as `@ts-ignore` would otherwise nullify both:

```
// @ts-ignore separate noUnusedLocals error from the type assertion error
type _ = AssertThatReallyImplemented
interface AssertThatReallyImplemented extends ObjectIfImplemented { }
```

For testing purposes, the assertion type can be made generic like this:

```
type AssertAssignable<T, U extends T> = true

// @ts-ignore success case
type _ = Assert
type Assert = AssertAssignable<readonly ISmth<any>[], typeof a> 

// @ts-ignore error case
type _ = AssertError
type AssertError = AssertAssignable<readonly ISmth<any>[], typeof aError> // error(OK!)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noUnusedLocals=true&ssl=31&ssc=88&pln=23&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWAeAFQD5kBvAWAChllgATALmRAFdMAjaAbiprrjBwmBHpQC+VKhAAeABwD2UMMgBucKMjjIAvMgDaFarUbIAjABpeyfoKZ6AupfH3NAZ2QJ5IV2FFS5ispqGnAAolBQijr6hjT0TABEpglOfAJC+o5UYi5w7p7evpKUYACesigA8uwAVhAIYKgwqJiyADYQmBDgEHTRABRlFfIwmsgykCB07gBKEHB0Xm2leBjY+HAgpUQOJAD8yNV1DchMIBAq0ACUfpQA9HfIAAJgrgC0wADmIIoorhCydQCFA-ACqrH+dAAMvIEHA2u5oJENDBIphkLgUEMUHl-kpgF5xhFFFRscgAPrRACCrjxYAIOAEc3hyxa7U63UgdCooEgsEQKBpdIZTPmbVZrQ6XR6fQm3Wmh1q9UazUlHJlZGQYmQxVJ5UFtOgYCFXxAcHYHUI5mQoPG0kmCuI0TAUBYEGKD2erw+31+yFcLAQSFpHjy7pK+op1MNSj1FWQQqN0bpJu+5stUHmixAyzQWFweE22wc1uxI00JA9jxe71NfqRUTh-zjKEpukTSnCyJbCZjYC7UXbfdTZotEDwmYWS1KefWha2O0cGP15bCxKgJE9Dag-UqAGkAIRXKhAA)

Comment: 1. Seems like this answer is more suitable for [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58437445/4928642). Maybe you'll move it there? 2. I actually don't like idea of creating runtime stuff (like function calls) for the things that actually don't need it. 3. Your version works with objects, but not with types, so it's not applicable to types.

Comment: Great! By the way, I like you way of checking type compatibility. If you post it in that question, I'll accept it there.

Comment: Thank you. You mean the `AssertAssignable` type?

Comment: Yep, `AssertAssignable`.